# Dictionary<something, List<>> flatten (ungroup) to List of something and elements from List - C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, grouping

I want to flatten (ungroup) my dictionary - and trying if it can be done by Linq.

Sample input:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>();
dict.Add(0, new List<string>() { "a", "b" });
dict.Add(1, new List<string>() { "c", "d"});
```

What i want to achieve is List of following elements:

> 0a
>
> 0b
>
> 1c
>
> 1d

of course it can be done with:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach (var element in dict)
{
    foreach (var valuesElement in element.Value)
    {
        output.Add(element.Key + valuesElement);
    }
}
```

I'm only looking if there is any "clever" linq construction to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `.SelectMany()`

```
dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => $"{x.Key}{y}"));
```

[Here's](https://www.dotnetperls.com/selectmany) more explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectMany` on the dictionary and the construct the items based on value in the key value pair

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>();
dict.Add(0, new List<string>() { "a", "b" });
dict.Add(1, new List<string>() { "c", "d" });

List<string> output = dict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => string.Format("{0}{1}", kvp.Key, v))).ToList();
```